# How to check stream writer flush called or not?

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter

I have 2 places where I am calling `writer.Flush()` method like:

```
StreamWriter writer;
....
writer.Flush();
```

How to check was `writer.Flush()` called or not?

there is my code:

```
            var writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.Body);
            try
            {
await Router.DownloadHandler.ProcessAsync(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                WriteException(writer, ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                await writer.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                writer.Dispose();
            }
```

I can not use autoflush because in some cases I have to add custom headers.

But in my case the solution is:
Just move await writer.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); from finally block to the try block.
But in general, the question is still open.

Comment: You can put it in a method that will keep track of the calls (e.g. set a boolean flag if it was called).

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what are you using Flush for?

Comment: Sounds like it might be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...

Comment: I am getting a stream writer based on response body.

Comment: And secound places I have common exception handler and this exception handler has a stream writer as a parameter and also call flush method inside.

Comment: Calling `Flush` is very rarely necessary if you are always correctly disposing your streams with `using`. Please show more code, as currently this seems to be an XY problem.

Comment: @Charlieface : If auto flush is turned off or you close before flush often you miss saving end of file.  You either need to flush or put the stream in a using block which will dispose and flush automatically.

Comment: @jdweng That's exactly what I said: if you dispose your stream then it gets flushed. There is never a need to flush if you have a `using`.